# Website is redirecting back to login page after successful authentication

Tags: asp.net, cookies, webforms, asp.net-identity, application-pool

I have a website in production server, asp.net webforms using Asp.Net Identity system.

Sometimes, when users tries to login, it redirects then back to login page after successful authentication thereby denying them access to user dashboard and other secured pages.

The temporary solution to this is for me to Recycle Application Pools in the hosting server (via plesk). But it appears again after some time. Sometimes before 24hrs or more.

The issue most often occurs when multiple users are getting logged in at a range of time... From my observation.

I don't know the main cause of the issue and I'm seeking a permanent fix to it. What could be the issue? How can I resolve this?

Useful hint:

After authentication at the login page, I usually create a response cookie which holds other value which I use to keep track of the user. If the cookie expires, I redirect the user back to login. I usually check for existence of this cookie on the master page for each page load. So I don't know if this could be a possible cause. If it is, whats the best practice to employ?

I've tried checking the cookies being set if it's the possible challenge, but no success.

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? could be a samesite cookie issue?

Comment: Yes. HTTPS cookie

Comment: can you post some code and also how you set the cookies? are they logged out when you do redeploy the app?